# How rename (and remove) axis and legends in ggord plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(15)

df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(6, rnorm(n = 30, mean = 200, sd = 20)), 
  y = as.factor(sample(x = 1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE))
)
```

I did this discriminant analysis:

```
library(MASS)

discriminant <- lda(y ~ ., data = df_1)
```

I tried rename (or remove) the axis labels and legends topics with `ggord` package.

```
library(ggord)

ggord(discriminant, 
  df_1$y, 
  veccol = 'transparent', 
  vec_lab = (''), 
  grp_title = 'Clusters')
```

[image]

- I can not rename and delete label names (`LD1` and `LD2`);
- I want too rename the groups names in `Clusters` legend (instead `1` rename to `group_1`...).

I tried remove with follow arguments:

```
labcol = 'transparent'
add_col = 'transparent'
```

and rename with:

```
axes = c("new_lab_x", "new_lab_y")
```

But, doesn't work.

For `legends` (`Cluster`), I could not use any argument...

Comment: What have you tried in order to change those labels?

Comment: I tried remove with follow arguments: `labcol = 'transparent',
add_col = 'transparent'` and rename with: `axes = c("group_1", "group_2", ...)`

Comment: It's better if you can [edit] the question to include that code in full, since that's the part you're trying to debug

Comment: To remove or change the axis name you can always pull down the function with `getAnywhere(ggord.lda)` modify the names of the obs by changing the second to the last line to `names(obs)[1:2] <- ""` and then assign the function to a different name. Then use that new function to graph the data.

Comment: @ c1au61o_HH can you show me a answer? Tks.